# Mock browser document in integration test

Tags: javascript, testing, meteor, mocha.js, integration-testing

How can I mock standard whole browser's `window` on client? I want entirely new object same as `window` which would provide work with location and DOM but would not render into actual displayed window. There is JSDOM which works on server, but I would like the possibility on client. I'm using Meteor with Mocha.

I came up with solution to call `window.open()` and use returned value, but it comes with problems with pop-blocker and I guess it's pretty slow.

Comment: "Pretty slow" should be a minor concern when doing integration tests. Validity and integrity are way more important. Why would you need to mock the entire DOM from the window object (with **all** it's functionality)?

Comment: Just to be sure that it works as in native window. I would like to rather make new instance same as window, not create object that resembles existing window object.